# MSSQL A constant expression was encountered in the ORDER BY list, position 1

Tags: sql-server, sql-order-by

## Problem:

This is an Query, that should sort a Table, it works fine if at leat one value in column "archived" is not null, but in my case, it is possible and valid that all values of archived column can be null.

When at least one value is not null, then it should be sorted.

## Sample1 (works):

```
id|Archived
0 |NULL
1 |NULL
2 |0
3 |1
```

## Sample2 (not working, but possible and valid szenario):

```
id|Archived
0 |NULL
1 |NULL
2 |NULL
3 |NULL
```

## Query example:

```
SELECT ... FROM Table1 
   ORDER BY 
      CASE archived WHEN NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END DESC,
      CASE id WHEN NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END DESC
```

## How to solve such problems?

Comment: Edit the question add some sample data & desired result would helpful.

Comment: thx, i have edited the initial post

Comment: If `archived` is a bit nullable field, then you may be better off ordering by `COALESCE(archived, 1)`

Comment: You did not explain how you want your data sorted. First the nulls and after the non nulls? First by archived and then by id? Is there a case that id could be null?

Comment: the problem is, that ORDER BY tells me, it can not be sorted by a constant value. I want that the result is sorted as following: if NOT archived, at the top, all archived entries at bottom. My Problem is, that ORDER BY not simply ignores that the values for archived are the same. in this case the sorting ist not important for me. only sorting is important if there are values that would get archived in this case. i hope you understand what i mean. thx for any hints

Answer (score -1, accepted):

From the working sample I don't think you want the data sorted descending, right?

```
SELECT ... FROM Table1 
   ORDER BY 
      CASE WHEN archived IS NULL THEN -1 ELSE archived END,
      CASE WHEN id IS NULL THEN -1 ELSE id END
```

Comment: How can you know the direction of ordering that OP wants? The issue was never that, it was the syntax.

Comment: Did you see the working sample? The data is ordered ascending.

Comment: can someone pls explain the difference between this and my snippet? thx

Comment: Null is not comparable. So case id when null is never true. You must do case when id is null. Also you are sorting first the non nulls and then the nulls.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use that format of the `CASE` statement in an `ORDER BY`. Instead you can do this:

```
SELECT ... FROM Table1 
   ORDER BY 
      CASE WHEN archived IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END DESC,
      CASE WHEN id IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END DESC
```

Comment: This will sort all the nulls at the end. The exact opposite of what the OP wants.

Comment: OP can fix the ordering then, I am fixing the syntax error.

Comment: The question is not about a syntax error, but about the ordering.

Comment: The error is literally the title of the question, how can it not be about that?

Comment: And thanks for the DV, I wanted to remove mine from yours but I can't because it's locked in until you edit again.

Comment: You wanted but you did not

Comment: Why would I lie?

Comment: Every time I see a syntax error in an answer, first I post a comment and wait and if nothing happens then **maybe** I downvote. Not the other way around.

Comment: Unless the question is asking to fix that syntax error, which it is.

Comment: MSSQL A constant expression was encountered in the ORDER BY list, position 1 -> is a RUNTIME Error btw

Comment: @Patric There's no such thing as a "runtime error" in SQL Server.

Comment: maybe my wording is bad, this wasnt a syntax problem, the query syntax is ok, but while query executions, this message was shown. therefore no syntax problem.